# SSRS : No results retrieved or appearing because of

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have this report on SSRS

[image]

The above highlighted field has the following formula (see below for the formula)

[image]

All the results are retrieved by a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SIGLEENSEIGNE]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        CASE    WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%' AND John_Jack.Enseigne IS NOT NULL AND John_Jack.Enseigne <> ''
                    THEN '      / ' + John_Jack.Enseigne
                WHEN (John_Jack.Sigle IS NULL OR John_Jack.Sigle ='')
                    AND (John_Jack.Enseigne IS NULL OR John_Jack.Enseigne ='')
                    THEN ''
                ELSE John_Jack.Sigle + ' / ' + John_Jack.Enseigne
            END as SigleEnseigne1
            FROM    John_Jack
END
```

**updated part**

No results are appearing because when I use this `First(Fields!SigleEnseigne1.Value, "SigleEnseigne")`, it only gets me the first row and the first row is empty ...

From my discussion with @Jonnus, I must have another column in my stored procedure or stored somewhere else , for ssrs to do the lookup and to use the second dataset.

I don't like the idea as it will get ridiculously tedious, I'm therefore all ears if you have any other solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @mike-honey , if you have any insights, I'm all ears

Comment: Do you get an error of any type, or is it just blank?

Comment: Hi @Jonnus, just blank.

Comment: @Jonnus: It took me some time to understand but I've nailed it finally : 

I'm using two different datasets. The first one was doing fine as there was only a single region. However, when I'm using a second dataset, it is giving me the first record and only the first one `First(Fields!SigleEnseigne1.Value, "DataSet3")`. When trying to remove the first to have this `(Fields!SigleEnseigne1.Value, "DataSet3") "DataSet3")`, I have the error : ** Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope**.


Is it a way to use 2 dataset without using `lookup` or `LookUpSet`?

Comment: No, the only way to reference a second dataset on a record by record basis is using a lookup expression. Alternatively toucan reference the first record only as you have been doing currently

Comment: @Jonnus: I've seen better days but I will overcome :)

Questions then : I have my sp that is bringing me the wanted results. Should I amend the SP, creating a second column , to be able to do a `lookup` on it? If no, do you have any advices I can use? My stored procedure is on my question

Comment: Yes, I would have the second sp return two columns (probably the one you are getting your table on)

Comment: Thanks @Jonnus. Have a good weekend

Comment: Hi @Jonnus, quick question , which is a continuation of this question: Why the dataset has to be shared in order to do the trick?

Comment: @AndyK can you show a sample output of your sp? I would like to see how many data are you populating from that sp. Because you are like calling a list from your sp and just using one of them in your table that's why you use first in your expression.

Comment: @Andy K. It doesn't have to be a shared dataset.

Comment: and if you are just using only one dataset in that table. you could use this **Fields!SigleEnseigne1.Value** because if you use **First(Fields!SigleEnseigne1.Value, "DataSet3")** you will surely get only the first value.

Comment: Hi @bot, thanks for your help. I've been able to fix the issue , by using `lookup` with another field and now it is working a treat. Please see my updated sp in the question